# Problems with event listening while re-rendering SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dom-events

I have next situation:
I made a lib that draws charts. I have zooming there. When you triggering 'mousewheel' event - chart re-rendering with new scale. But there is a trouble in almost all browsers (except of Chrome). In Chrome you are getting 'mousewheel' event many times on one wheel move. In other browsers you getting event, chart's re-rendering, and there are no more events and you should make more moves to get events. Does anybody know how to resolve this problem? Or maybe I have a bad architecture of code?

Here is wheelHandler:

```
function wheelHandler() {
    var pad = d3.event.type === 'mousewheel' ? d3.event.wheelDeltaY / 10 : d3.event.detail,
    newKoefficient = koefficient + pad;
    newKoefficient = Math.max(newKoefficient, config.minZoom);
    newKoefficient = Math.min(newKoefficient, config.maxZoom);
    if (newKoefficient !== koefficient) {
        koefficient = newKoefficient;
        render();
    }
}
```

While rendering I emptying svg-container and re-building elements in it.

Comment: @RobertLongson thx, i made changes;)

Comment: @RobertLongson I am catching two events - 'mousewheel' and 'DOMMouseScroll'

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you mate! Now it works, but I still have problems, when I using trackpad instead of mouse. Don't you know how can i fix it?

Comment: no, i can't get such event.
I mean same case, when you scrolling something with two fingers on your touchpad/trackpad

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Probably best to ask another question with a complete example in it.

Answer (score 1):

You should [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) events rather than [mousewheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) events as mousewheel events are only implemented on Chrome.